# Russian language in lstlisting

Tags: listings, code, russian

I am using LaTeX on overleaf.com and trying to use russian language in code, but the compiler gives an error "Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence".

I can use russian text freely out of code scopes.

My LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=C++
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 3;
//привет1
\end{lstlisting}

привет2

\end{document}
```

So after I compile my program I see no russian words in code:

[image]

How is it possible to use russian language in code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How is the input file encoded? Is it utf8?

Comment: @Mico I think yes, I can add line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if it is necessarry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use literate. The can find the command names in t2aenc.dfu.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    literate={п}{\cyrp}1
             {и}{\cyri}1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 3;
//пи
пи
\end{lstlisting}

привет {\itshape привет}

\end{document}
```

[image]